# tool to create repository on local machine and allow checkins and source control locally

Tags: version-control, local, fedora

I am developing on Fedora. I don't have any remote server or so. But I want to setup something to help me does "source control" of the changes that I make locally - allow me to create repositories, checkin, checkout, look at history etc, all just on my machine. Is there such tool available on Fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [Git](http://git-scm.com/), following the instructions at [Using Fedora Git](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Fedora_GIT).
(See also the "[installing Git](http://linux.yyz.us/git-howto.html#installing_git)" section, for instance)

As a DVCS, you will have the full history of your repo in a *local* `.git` directory.

Note: [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) would be, [on Fedora](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download#Linux_.28.rpm.29), an equally valid choice.